# Wildcard search in CloudSearch

Tags: amazon-web-services, lucene, amazon-cloudsearch

I need to perform wildcard queries on numbers on CloudSearch. Doing it on textual data is easy -> xy* but it gives error while running the same query for number fields. I am using lucene as a query parser. Please suggest if it can be don using any other parsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wildcard searches are not supported for numeric fields. From your question it is unclear what kind of result you are expecting.

If you are expecting to match a range of numbers then you can use a **range query**:

`numericField:[330 TO 339]`

will match documents where `numericField` is greater than or equal to 330 and less than or equal to 339.

If, on the other hand, you are expecting to find all documents where the first and second digits are threes, for example, you would need another textual field that contains the string representation of the number. You would search on it like this:

`numericFieldAsText:33*`

This would match `33`, `331`, `333`, `330001` etc.

Comment: I dont have a text representation of the numeric field. Is there any way to obtain the same results on numeric fields without having to add another field that has the string representation of the number

Answer (score 1):

You can use filter query as `(and (prefix field=field_name 'xy'))` if it is a structured query.
but if it is a simple query then you can use directly xy* in search.